# How do i read a google spreadsheet in flex and as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, spreadsheet

I want access gps coordinates from a Google spreadsheet to be able to position markers in my google maps flex air app.

I have made the spreadsheet public for anyone with the link.
But how do I access it with as3?

Thanks

/Andreas

Answer (score 1):

In google docs.  You can share the spreadsheet as a CSV file. When you do that you are given a URL.  In AS3 you can download the content of this URL and parse the data as CSV data.  You may need to find a CSV library.